# fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/" in SFTP

Tags: ssh, debian, sftp

I've been trying to configure sftp in a debian server.`sshd_config:`

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

UsePAM no

Match User sftpUser
ChrootDirectory /users/sftp/sftpUser
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

Directories:

```
 drwxr-xr-x   3 root      root      4096 Oct 20 10:59 users

 drwxr-xr-x   3 root      root      4096 Oct 20 11:00 sftp

 drwxr-xr-x   2 root      root      4096 Oct 20 11:00 sftpUser
```

`cat /var/log/auth.log`

```
Oct 20 10:58:22 w1 sshd[24634]: Accepted password for sftpUser from 201.156.103.213 port 34106 ssh2
Oct 20 10:58:22 w1 sshd[24636]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"
```

sftpUser no home, `bin/false`and member of user group.

In the client side I'm getting the famous `Write failed: Broken pipe` and then the connection is dropped. 
Commenting the `ChrootDirectory`command in sshd_config makes the connection, but get's the user loose.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: it is a very basic problem and the auth .log is telling you what exactly the problem is: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot

Comment: Run `ls -ld /` and show the output.

Comment: You're right !!!!
`drwxr-xr-x 28 suzukiweb suzukiweb 4096 Oct 20 10:59 / ` 
It seems that root directory (/) is owned by other user, but listing without -ld modifier didn't show it...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `ChrootDirectory` option in `sshd_config` requires some basic understanding of written text.

This is snapshot from manual page for `sshd_config(5)`:

> **ChrootDirectory**
>
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to `chroot(2)` to after authentication.  *All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.  After the chroot, `sshd(8)` changes the working directory to the user's home directory.*

This is your error log:

```
fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"
```

This means that you need to make sure to fulfil the emphasised part of the quote: Your `/` need to be owned by root and has `w` acl only for the owner.

Comment: this is users directory. How does root directory look like, as proposed in comments? `ls -ld /`

Comment: With your answer combined with the comment provided by Michael Hampton the problem was solved. It seems that the root (/) directory was owned by another user different from root. Corrected it whith:
`chown root:root /`

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please mark it as a solution so it can help the others.

Comment: I want to clarify, that `/` means *"directory that becomes / for chrooted user"*

Comment: @Kondybas No. In this case, the `/` is really `/` of filesystem which has the wrong permissions. But the error can look different way if you have the permissions wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @Jakuje It's obvious that real `/` can become owned by non-root user only by mistake or (way more likely) by misunderstanding of chroot manuals.

Comment: @Kondybas as you can read in the question comments, the mistake really happened and the `/` was really owned by user `suzukiweb` (which is obviously wrong).