# Allowing both SFTP and SSH with chrooted directory

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I am attempting to set up a user with SFTP access and limited SSH access. Therefore, I've chrooted the user and then set it up basically exactly as specified in [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/jail-ssh-user-to-home-directory-on-linux). However, while I can ssh into the server successfully, when I attempt to connect via an SFTP connection, it simply says Connection Failed.

**Research and attempted fixes**

I have attempted searching for anything that can explain how to do this however I could only find [this topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/822983/chrooted-ssh-sftp-doesnt-work) which did not have any answers. In addition, there were no articles online that I could find that showed how this could be done.

I also tried copying the entire `/bin` and entire `/lib` folder into the chrooted directory in order to ensure that there wasn't any missing commands that may be causing it to fail. Looking at `/var/log/auth.log` yielded no results including as the only log was that the connection was closed by the user including when I set `LogLevel Debug2` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Attempting to connect using an SCP connection in WinSCP allows me to see the files, however I can't copy anything to my local drive or vice versa

**SSHD Config File (relevant section):**

```
Match User test_user
    ChrootDirectory /home/test_user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found the `jailkit` tool which is designed to automate the jailing of users rather than doing it manually which I originally was attempting to do.

To set up the chrooted directory, I used the following steps

**Installation (on Ubuntu)**
Installation from source can be found [here](https://www.binarytides.com/install-jailkit-ubuntu-debian/)

```
sudo apt install jailkit
```

**Directory Setup**

A list of various packages to allow access to can be found at `/etc/jailkit/jk_init.ini`. I also installed git this way after I had set it up

```
sudo chown root:root /srv/test_user
sudo jk_init -v /srv/test_user netutils basicshell jk_lsh openvpn ssh sftp
```

General format below

```
sudo chown root:root <chroot_directory>
sudo jk_init -v <chroot_directory> <packages>
```

**Jailing the user**

```
sudo jk_jailuser -m -j /srv/test_user test_user
```

**Changing shell**

Finally the shell specified in `<chroot_directory>/etc/passwd` should be changed from `/usr/sbin/jk_lsh` to `/bin/bash`. Note there should only be the entries for test_user, root and possibly one other login

From there, you can log in via ssh or sftp/scp and access everything as expected. Note that to log in via public key, you will need to set up the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file