# sftp, chroot + chdir to user home?

Tags: ssh, configuration, sftp

Have a config that looks like [this](https://serverfault.com/a/730333/51913)

```
AllowUsers sftpu
Match Group sftpg
    ChrootDirectory /home/sftp
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

the `passwd` entry (group 7700 is named `sftpg`)

```
sftpu:x:7700:7700::/home/sftp/allu:/bin/false
```

and the `allu` dir

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 guacam sftpg  4096 Sep 16  2019 /home/sftp/allu/
```

That almost works. The *chroot* works, but unlike what the man says

> After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory

the working dir of the user after login is `/home/sftp`, not `/home/sftp/allu`, and my guess is that because `/home/sftp/allu` belongs to `guacam` and not `sftpu` (while the `sftpg` group has `rwx` access in `allu` and could write. That's because several users should share that same `allu` dir).

Unless the config above is flawed, is there a command in the sshd subsystem to either

- force the chdir (after chroot) to go to the user's home
- relax a bit the access rules
- ...

while keeping the same directory tree and accesses?

Comment: its the word **after** in the *After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory* description that means to tell the reader how paths are treated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sshd can't change the working directory to the user's home directory because it doesn't exist. It therefore leaves the working directory set to `/`.

You assigned this user the home directory `/home/sftp/allu`. But then you chroot the user to `/home/sftp`. That means that relative to the chroot, that directory is at `/allu`! Not `/home/sftp/allu`.

You need to know that chroot causes the root directory that the logged in user can access will be changed to some lower point in the filesystem, and that all paths are relative to that. So if a user must access `/home/sftp/allu` inside a chroot directory `/home/sftp`, then outside in the real filesystem, the directory would be `/home/sftp/home/sftp/allu`.

Comment: Indeed. Didn't think the `cd` to the user's home would occur while taking into account the chroot. Learned something today :-) Thanks